# Texture that doesn't get affected by scaling?

Tags: animation, texturing, game-engine, uv, logic-bricks

I have a simple plane that acts as a health bar in my HUD. I am putting a texture on it, but when the plane scales down the texture also does. How can I have the texture not affected by scaling? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to do that with Texture/Mapping/Coordinates set to global.

[image]